# How to create Generic Map/Zip Function that Transpose N Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming, transpose

I have N Arrays. How can I create a generic Map/Zip function that can transpose N number of arrays together. Please see code below for example. 
Also, how can i make it work for multidimensional arrays. 
Thank you.

```
// A Arrays
const arrayA1 = [{name: "James"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Jack"}]
const arrayA2 = [{age: 10}, {age: 20}, {age: 12}]

// B Arrays
const arrayB1 = [{name: "James"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Jack"}]
const arrayB2 = [{age: 10}, {age: 20}, {age: 12}]
const arrayB3 = [{height: 150}, {height: 200}, {height: 180}] 

const result = {}
const result1 = {}

// Transpose A Arrays Only (does not work for B Arrays)------ How can i make the  SAME function work for both A and B arrays
arrayA1.map((x, y) => {
  let abc = [x, arrayA2[y]];
  result1[y] = abc;   
  result[x.name] = arrayA2[y]
})


console.log(result);
// { James: { age: 10 }, John: { age: 20 }, Jack: { age: 12 } }

// WHICH IS BETTER IMPLEMENTATION >>>>>> result or result1 >> I intend to send to mongodb

console.log(result1);
/*
{ '0': [ { name: 'James' }, { age: 10 } ],
  '1': [ { name: 'John' }, { age: 20 } ],
  '2': [ { name: 'Jack' }, { age: 12 } ] }
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better result structure would be an array of objects, like

```
[
  {name: xxx, age: yyy},
  {name: xxx, age: yyy},
  {name: xxx, age: yyy}
]
```

Here's code to generate it:

```js
// A Arrays
const arrayA1 = [{name: "James"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Jack"}]
const arrayA2 = [{age: 10}, {age: 20}, {age: 12}]

// B Arrays
const arrayB1 = [{name: "James"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Jack"}]
const arrayB2 = [{age: 10}, {age: 20}, {age: 12}]
const arrayB3 = [{height: 150}, {height: 200}, {height: 180}]

//

zip = (...arrays) => arrays[0].map((_, n) => arrays.map(a => a[n]));

merge = (x, y) => Object.assign(x, y);

zipMerge = (...arrays) => zip(...arrays).map(props => props.reduce(merge, {}))

//

console.log(zipMerge(arrayA1, arrayA2))

console.log(zipMerge(arrayB1, arrayB2, arrayB3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just want to ask a followup question. if ** A Arrays** and **B Arrays* were wrapped in an object literal, how could the code be modified to take a single object parameter: 
`zipMerge(arraysA)` or `zipMerge(arraysB)` so i dont have to pass in many individual arrays as parameters.

Comment: @Ming: to make `zip` accept an array of arrays instead of variable arguments, just remove the splat operator `...`

Comment: Thanks @georg How can i learn to code functionally like this. is there any resources or books. Also should I be using libraries (ramda, lodash etc...) or just use native functions in js (map, reduce, filter)

Comment: @Ming: https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ is pretty decent